# Data migration from S3 to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-dms, aws-data-pipeline

I am working on a requirement, where i am doing multipart upload of the csv file from on prem server to S3 Bucket.

To achieve this using AWS Lambda I create a presigned url and use this url i am uploading the csv file. Now, once i have the file in AWS S3, i want it to be moved to AWS RDS Oracle DB. Initially i was planning to use AWS Lambda for this.

So once i have the file in S3, it triggers lambda(s3 event) and lambda will push this file to RDS. But with this the issue is with the file Size(600 MB).

I am looking for some other way, where whenever there is a file uploaded to S3, it should trigger any AWS service and that service will push this csv file to RDS. I have gone through AWS DMS/Data Pipeline, but not able to find any way to automate this migration

I need to automate this migration on every s3 upload, that is also cost effective.

Comment: Is it partial or full data?

Comment: @mokugo-devops in S3? yeah full data.. means when i have the full data in S3, i want it to be migrated. But the data is more than 500 MB.

Comment: So the process needs to replace the database?

Comment: No in database i need to make an entry in the existing DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup S3 Integration and build SPROCS to help automate load. Details found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/oracle-s3-integration.html).

*UPDATE:*

Looks like you don't even need to create a SPROC. You can just use the RDS procedure as outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/oracle-s3-integration.html#oracle-s3-integration.using.download). You would then just create an event-driven lambda function that is triggered on a given S3 event--e.g. on object PUT(), POST(), COPY, etc..--which passes the S3 metadata requisite to access the event object. [Here](https://n2ws.com/blog/aws-automation/lambda-function-s3-event-triggers) is a simple Python example of what that Lambda and config might look like. You would then use the metadata passed on the trigger event--as outlined in the Python example--to dynamically create your procedure call then execute that procedure. You can also add the ensuing workflow logic that meets your requirements--i.e. `TASK_ID` fetch & operational handling, monitoring, etc...--to the same lambda function or separate those concerns by adding additional lambdas. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can i add s3 event in this to trigger the migration on every single upload.

Comment: Also where should i place the SPROCS to automate this.

Comment: Thanks @benfarr . I tried this, it worked. But still i need to call the stored Proc manually to migrate the data.

Comment: No problem, @Nimmo. I just updated the response that should help you work through the rest. If you needed to add a custom SPROC to complete additional work, you can trigger your custom SPROC from your lambda function as well.

Comment: Thank you @benfarr. Its working. I am getting the task id in response while running "SELECT rdsadmin.rdsadmin_s3_tasks.download_from_s3(p_bucket_name =>'destintion', p_directory_name => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR') AS TASK_ID FROM DUAL" query. Can i dump this data in rds table? Also i am not able to see the data in sql. Just i am getting the task id.

Comment: You're welcome, @Nimmo. Yes, you can load the contents of the file to a table. Depending on the export format, there are a number of ways of going about accomplishing that. You can read the contents of the file from with the following--maybe not best idea with file size:
`SELECT text FROM table(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.read_text_file('BDUMP','dbtask-<task-id>.log'));`
`DBMS_DATAPUMP` allows you to import the file to the target instance schema. Lots of options with this package as outlined here[link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_datpmp.htm#ARPLS356)

Comment: @Nimmo if these are all standard .csv files, [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm#BABCJCBD) might be a better/less convoluted option for your use case.

Comment: Do we have a procedure like  "SELECT rdsadmin.rdsadmin_s3_tasks.download_from_s3(p_bucket_name =>'my-s3-bucket', p_directory_name => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR') AS TASK_ID FROM DUAL". But i need destination as the table which is having my source csv data. I dont want to create a directory in rds.

Comment: I am still facing this issue. I need to copy the data of the file in the table not the file itself. This procedure is create a file in a directory. I want the data in Oracle table.